# Retrieve ArrayList from Firebase and display it in ListView

Tags: java, android, firebase, listview, arraylist

[image]I'm using Firebase to store information for an app I'm making in Android.

Currently I have the functionality to be able to retrieve an object from Firebase and populate a listView of these objects. However when I place an Order, I'm making an ArrayList of these objects and saving it that way. So when I try to retrieve and display the orders, I'm getting an error saying cannot convert ArrayList to type Object.

Here's the code for the retrieval and display:

```
 public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                Object object = ds.getValue(Object.class);

                orders.add(object);
                list.setAdapter(adapter);

            }
        }
```

So here we have orders is an ArrayList, and object is an instance of my Object class. I have this code in another area of the application working fine, when it's retrieving all of the items in my database and populating my feed, but these items are being stored as individual items in the db and not as an Array of items.

How can I retrieve the ArrayList from my db and then access the specific items within that ArrayList? If you'd like code from any other area of the application just ask and I will edit/update my question to include that code. Thanks

Comment: Can you show screenshot of your firebase database? I know the solution

Comment: @RahulChandrabhan I've added a photo to the question above

Comment: which node you want to read?

Comment: So I'd like the listView to show the entire bookList. 0/1/2 etc represent the books that are in that order, so they should populate my listView

Comment: I am posting the code in 5 min

Comment: What are the fields inside those arrays?

Comment: Information for the book, title author price image stock info category

Comment: Check my answer, you have to just add those fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample POJO:

```
public class BookList {

    private String bookName; // Add fields according to your needs \\

    public BookList(){

    }


    public String getBookName() {
        return bookName;
    }

    public void setBookName(String bookName) {
        this.bookName = bookName;
    }
}
```

Method for fetching book details:

```
private void fetchBookList() {
        progressDialog();

        //---Your Reference to the bookList---\\
DatabaseReference dbRefQuoteRequestList = firebaseDatabase.getReference("All_Orders").child("Anthony Hopkins")
                .child("orders").child("bookList");
        dbRefQuoteRequestList.addValueEventListener(new com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(final com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                quoteRequestListArrayList.clear(); // ArrayList<Pojo/Object> \\

                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    String bookName = postSnapshot.child("bookName").getValue(String.class);
                    //Use the dataType you are using and also use the reference of those childs inside arrays\\

                    // Putting Data into Getter Setter \\
                    BookList bookList = new BookList();
                    bookList.setbookName(bookName);

                    quoteRequestListArrayList.add(bookList);

                }

                if (quoteRequestListArrayList.size() == 0) {
                    StaticMethods.customSnackBar(quoteRequestLv, "Your alert!",
                            getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark),
                            getResources().getColor(R.color.color_white), 3000);
                }

                //---Initialize your adapter as you have fetched the data---\\
                quoteRequestListAdapter = new QuoteRequestListAdapter(QuoteRequestListActivity.this, quoteRequestListArrayList);
                quoteRequestLv.setAdapter(quoteRequestListAdapter);

                dismissDialog();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Change the name according to your needs, Hope it helps.

Comment: you sir are too kind. I really appreciate that help!

Comment: I was changing it around with my variables/adapters etc and SUCCESS!! Thanks for all the help!